# Disable the XCode LaunchScreen at startup in a React Native app?

Tags: xcode, react-native

Is there a way to disable the LaunchScreen at startup? I know how to remove contents of the LaunchScreen but I really want to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple [requires](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) you to supply a launch screen. You can instead supply a static image, but then you'd have to make different sizes for different devices.

Comment: Ok thanks I was sure it was a part of iOS specs. ;-)